# jquery image gallery is not working as it should

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

i am trying to create a simple photo gallery where one photo is big and there are also thumbinals at the bottom which when clicked become that big photo. Galleries are in separate modal windows. My code only works in the first modal window.
In fact this is my very first time using jquery. I can't even find how to use the console.log to check where the problem is.

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img id="big" src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg">
        
            <div id="thumbnails">
                <a href="foto/20210218_135910.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210218_135910 small.jpg"></a>
                <a href="foto/20210322_100211.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_100211 small.jpg"></a>
                <a href="foto/20210322_153418.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_153418 small.jpg"></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
         <!--other content-->
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img id="big" src="foto/20210322_153418.jpg">
        
            <div id="thumbnails">
                <a href="foto/20210218_135910.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210218_135910 small.jpg"></a>
                <a href="foto/20210322_100211.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_100211 small.jpg"></a>
                <a href="foto/20210322_153418.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_153418 small.jpg"></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
         <!--other content-->
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
   $("#thumbnails a").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      $("#big").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    });
```

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

IDs are identifiers, and identifiers must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**id have to be uniq** to avoid problem..

eliminate id="big" and replace id="thumbnails"  by class="thumbnails"

```js
$(".thumbnails a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest(".gallery").find("img").first().attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal_content">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg">

    <div class="thumbnails">
      <a href="foto/20210218_135910.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210218_135910 small.jpg"></a>
      <a href="foto/20210322_100211.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_100211 small.jpg"></a>
      <a href="foto/20210322_153418.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_153418 small.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--other content-->
</div>

<div class="modal_content">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="foto/20210322_153418.jpg">

    <div class="thumbnails">
      <a href="foto/20210218_135910.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210218_135910 small.jpg"></a>
      <a href="foto/20210322_100211.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_100211 small.jpg"></a>
      <a href="foto/20210322_153418.jpg"><img src="foto/resized/20210322_153418 small.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--other content-->
</div>
```

explanation:

`$(this).closest(".gallery")`    means find the first parent with class `gallery`

`find("img").first()`    means find the childrens with tag img  and select first

---

if you replace `id="big"` by `class="big"`

you could write too:

```
$(".thumbnails a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest(".gallery").find("img.big").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: I think you need to set `.find("#big")` insted of `.find("img")`

Comment: @Bhautik negative, id must be uniq and big is not uniq

Comment: omg.. I have to take a break :D  When I switched to classes, everything works just fine! and i knew about this thing with ids..  Thanks to everyone!:)

Answer (score 0):

Find closest using jquery `closest()` and the find `#big` and replace.

```js
$("#thumbnails a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".gallery").find(".big").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```css
.modal_content{text-align:center;margin-top:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal_content">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img class="big" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        
            <div id="thumbnails">
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/151"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/151"></a>
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/152"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/152"></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
         <!--other content-->
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img class="big" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        
            <div id="thumbnails">
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/151"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/151"></a>
                <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/152"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/152"></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
         <!--other content-->
    </div>
```

Comment: id must be uniq, its not the case here,    so you could have some problems..